# Apigee BaaS for system level notifications

Tags: javascript, cordova, notifications, apigee

I am implementing PUSH for my Phonegap Android App. To do so, I am referring to this blog and the PUSH example in the JS SDK.

http://apigee.com/docs/api-baas/content/introducing-push-notifications

Now, all along I see that there is a mention of an In App push. I am in my app and I get a new notification and I react to this. While this is fine, I also need Apigee BaaS to push notification to Android's status bar (where I see other notifications like WhatsApp, SMS etc).

Is it possible to achieve that? If so, can you kindly point me at a blog? (I couldn't find one)

Answer (score 0):

It might be that your notification priority is too low. This android.com article might help:

http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/notifications.html